# Reference a value from one cell in another cell (SQL)

Tags: sql

I am not sure if this is possible. I have done a lot of searching but I keep finding answers about inserting a value one time, not keeping a reference.

At my work I am 'internationalising' some webpages, which means making a database entry for every piece of text. There is one piece of text that has a link in it, and the link is stored in the database already. Having the code that referenced the link in the database cell didn't work (it just printed out as plain text), so my solution was to have the first half on the paragraph as one database entry (ending in `...<a href="`), and the second half as another (starting with `">click here</a>...),` and have the reference to the link in the middle. However my supervisor didn't like that.

So, what I would LIKE to be able to do, is have one database entry for the whole paragraph, and in the middle of it, refer to the link which is in another table (actually the same table, different sub-table). That way, the link will stay updated if it is ever changed (rather than hard-coding it into the paragraph text).

If it is impossible, that's totally fine, just want to confirm it (I can't seem to find anyone else who wanted to do this same thing and has been told it's impossible).

Thanks!

Comment: I think your initial approach is correct. The other one will result in development and most certainly severe maintenance costs. Chances are that your supervisor will never admit to have caused such costs with his/her decision, so guess who will be blamed eventually :-)

Comment: Thanks Giorgios. However, it did get me thinking - if this becomes the pattern, what if on another page there is a paragraph with several things referenced in the database already, then the specs change - changing, deleting, or adding more things is going to get really tricky.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is totally possible. All you need to do is to design a **trigger** on the table at insert and update event. whenever the link is entered or updated, the trigger will update the paragraph column as per your coding inside the trigger.

If you can share the table and fields, I can help you to write that trigger too :)

Comment: Thanks! Just the keyword I was looking for. To actually create the trigger is a bit above my pay grade (I can update rows, add rows, make new subtables), but I'll work out what's required and pass that on.

Comment: Good luck my friend :)